# Displaying HTML page only to logged in users using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, password-protection

I have a simple html page which i protect with Firebase.

I would like someones opinion on whether the way i do it is safe or not.

To check if the user is logged in or not, i have placed a javascript function in the header. I noticed that when i tried to access the page without being logged in i could see the content of the page for a split second, before being redirected. I therefore added an id to the body, and set display to none, until it's verified if the user is logged in. See code:

```
<script>
    const auth = firebase.auth()
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      document.getElementById("body").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      window.location.replace("/login.html")
    }
  });
</script>
```

My question is: Do you see any problems in doing it this way? Are there any security issues by doing it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a fairly common and simple way to prevent too much flashing while you're waiting for the user's authentication state to be determined.

The only better (but more involved) way that I know of to prevent the flash is to store your own marker value in local storage, which Michael showed in his I/O talk here: https://youtu.be/NwY6jkohseg?t=1309

Answer (score 0):

No, that's totally fine to do when using plain Javascript. Even if you were using a modern framework like Vue, you would store a data variable `isUserLoggedIn` or something to conditionally render UI.

If anyone uses browser dev tools to set display to `block`, that's not a threat as long as your have your security rules setup correctly.